# How to get page size from import PDF file with mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I have many PDF files with vary page size so when I use setSourceFile > importPage > useTemplate with default page size (A4). The content of some file with page size large than A4 will out of page.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    
    $arrPage = array(
        'orientation' => 'P',
        'mgl' => '0',
        'mgr' => '0',
        'mgt' => '0',
        'mgb' => '0',
        'mgh' => '0',
        'mgf' => '0',
        'newformat' => array(210,297)
    );

    $pagecount = $mpdf->setSourceFile($_GET['docFile']);
    
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
        $mpdf->AddPageByArray($arrPage);
        $tplId = $mpdf->importPage($i);
        $mpdf->useTemplate($tplId);
    }

    $mpdf->Output();
```

How can I get page size from import file so I can match page size before import file. Also page orientation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* ... */
$tplId = $mpdf->importPage($i);
$arrSize = $mpdf->getTemplateSize($tplId);
/* ... */
```

Comment: You save my life thank you very much. By the way I cannot find this method on the manual. Where is this come from?

Comment: I've made a research in mPDF code ;-)

Comment: It is a method from the external library used for importing pdf files, it is documented there: https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/#index-3